# Java Runtime crash when attempting to set JVM flags

Tags: java, docker, jvm, jvm-arguments

I have a microservice (springboot) inside a docker container. I am also passing a long list of JVM flags so that the program runs on that VM environment to test the latency values with each flag combination.

I am using this command to start the container:

> docker run --rm --name factorialorialContainer -p 8080:8080 -e
>   JAVA_OPTIONS="$(cat
>   /Users/sulekahelmini/Documents/fyp/fyp_work/MLscripts/flags.txt)"
>   suleka96/factorial:latest

The flags.txt looks like this:

> -XX:-ResizePLAB -XX:+ResizeOldPLAB -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -XX:-ParallelRefProcEnabled -XX:-ParallelRefProcBalancingEnabled -XX:-UseTLAB -XX:-ResizeTLAB -XX:+ZeroTLAB -XX:+FastTLABRefill -XX:-UseAutoGCSelectPolicy -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -XX:+UsePSAdaptiveSurvivorSizePolicy -XX:-UseAdaptiveGenerationSizePolicyAtMinorCollection -XX:+UseAdaptiveGenerationSizePolicyAtMajorCollection -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicyWithSystemGC -XX:+UseAdaptiveGCBoundary -XX:+UseAdaptiveSizePolicyFootprintGoal -XX:YoungPLABSize=4354 -XX:OldPLABSize=1141 -XX:GCTaskTimeStampEntries=255 -XX:TargetPLABWastePct=5 -XX:PLABWeight=73 -XX:OldPLABWeight=21 -XX:MarkStackSize=5927008 -XX:MarkStackSizeMax=579749070 -XX:RefDiscoveryPolicy=1 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=49 -XX:ErgoHeapSizeLimit=0 -XX:MaxRAMFraction=3 -XX:MinRAMFraction=3 -XX:InitialRAMFraction=74 -XX:AutoGCSelectPauseMillis=2934 -XX:AdaptiveSizeThroughPutPolicy=0 -XX:AdaptiveSizePausePolicy=0 -XX:AdaptiveSizePolicyInitializingSteps=24 -XX:AdaptiveSizePolicyOutputInterval=4060 -XX:AdaptiveSizePolicyWeight=11 -XX:AdaptiveTimeWeight=69 -XX:PausePadding=39200 -XX:PromotedPadding=3 -XX:SurvivorPadding=1 -XX:ThresholdTolerance=11 -XX:AdaptiveSizePolicyCollectionCostMargin=68 -XX:YoungGenerationSizeIncrement=28 -XX:YoungGenerationSizeSupplement=81 -XX:YoungGenerationSizeSupplementDecay=9 -XX:TenuredGenerationSizeIncrement=48 -XX:TenuredGenerationSizeSupplement=63 -XX:TenuredGenerationSizeSupplementDecay=2 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=16157174462788231168 -XX:GCPauseIntervalMillis=3009 -XX:GCTimeRatio=77 -XX:AdaptiveSizeDecrementScaleFactor=4 -XX:AdaptiveSizeMajorGCDecayTimeScale=9 -XX:MinSurvivorRatio=4 -XX:InitialSurvivorRatio=4 -XX:BaseFootPrintEstimate=463170010 -XX:GCHeapFreeLimit=4 -XX:ProcessDistributionStride=4 -Xms338224019 -Xmx1103493303

when I run the above-mentioned docker command I get the below error:

> #
>
> ## A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
> #
>
> ## SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f9b014fe3c3, pid=1, tid=0x00007f9b10633b10
>
> #
>
> ## JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_212-b04) (build 1.8.0_212-b04)
>
> ## Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.212-b04 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
>
> ## Derivative: IcedTea 3.12.0
>
> ## Distribution: Custom build (Sat May  4 17:33:35 UTC 2019)
>
> ## Problematic frame:
>
> ## j  java.net.URLStreamHandler.toExternalForm(Ljava/net/URL;)Ljava/lang/String;+88
>
> #
>
> ## Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
>
> #
>
> ## An error report file with more information is saved as:
>
> ## /usr/src/factorial/hs_err_pid1.log Compiled method (c1)    1054  256       1       java.net.URL::getRef (5 bytes)  total in heap
>
> [0x00007f9b0166bad0,0x00007f9b0166bd60] = 656  relocation
>   [0x00007f9b0166bbf8,0x00007f9b0166bc20] = 40  main code
>   [0x00007f9b0166bc20,0x00007f9b0166bca0] = 128  stub code
>   [0x00007f9b0166bca0,0x00007f9b0166bd30] = 144  scopes data
>   [0x00007f9b0166bd30,0x00007f9b0166bd38] = 8  scopes pcs
>   [0x00007f9b0166bd38,0x00007f9b0166bd58] = 32  dependencies
>   [0x00007f9b0166bd58,0x00007f9b0166bd60] = 8
>   #
>
> ## If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
>
> ## instructions on how to reproduce the bug and visit:
>
> ## https://icedtea.classpath.org/bugzilla
>
> #

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: do you have break lines in your txt file ? you can use shell vars: `export SOME_VARS = "-XX:..."` then `... -e JAVA_OPTIONS=${SOME_VARS}`, also try removing flags from your text file, like having only one, and keep adding them...

Comment: Just wow! Do you understand even 1/10 of the flags here? Some are duplicated, some are deprecated, some make no sense, and I only talking about the ones I know. Fantastic!

Comment: Do you have a Dockerfile/similar for us to reproduce this issue with? A minimal example?

Comment: Does this crash no longer occur if you disable the flags in question? Have you tried disabling the first half of the flags, and then the second half to narrow down which flags might be causing the issue?

Comment: I would also echo the sentiment that you probably do not need these flags.

Comment: @Eugene there are no duplicates, only very similar looking (sometimes contradicting) options. My Favorite is `-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=16157174462788231168`. Didn’t even know that the option parser handles values larger than `Long.MAX_VALUE`. But if you even encounter a GC pause larger than 512 mullion years, it’s a good idea to put a limit on it (but mind that this is not a hard limit)…

Comment: @Holger I have waited for the weekend to ask for your wisdom [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60248110/java-generic-type-issue/60248263#comment106576842_60248263), if that would not be too much to ask for

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's `-XX:+ZeroTLAB` option which is broken. Just don't use this flag.

I guess a random option generator is involved here for the purpose of performance tuning. While the idea itself is fine, and there are known cases<sup>1,2</sup> when Machine Learning with Bayesian Optimization helped to find better values of JVM options, the key point here is to include in the experiments only those options **which meaning and implications you understand well**.

Also the experiments should take care of **the reasonable ranges** of each option, as well as **the mutual relationship between connected options**.

However, the above option list looks totally random and does not make much sense (maybe, except for JVM testing). No surprise that such configuration may produce unpredictable results, including a JVM crash.

---

<sup>1</sup> [Automated Tuning of the JVM with Bayesian Optimization](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YhNl468S8CI)
<sup>2</sup> [Performance tuning Twitter services with Graal and Machine Learning](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W-5kUG8_mbk)

Answer (score 0):

Very similar I was to trying to run cassandra and it errored immediately with "Quit" thats it. The exit code was 131 which is some java type error. These were the flags:

```
-XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -XX:CompileCommandFile=/etc/cassandra/hotspot_compiler -XX:G1RSetUpdatingPauseTimePercent=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=10485760 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:InitialHeapSize=17179869184 -XX:+ManagementServer -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=500 -XX:MaxHeapSize=17179869184 -XX:MaxNewSize=2147483648 -XX:MaxRAMFraction=2 -XX:NewSize=2147483648 -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=kill -9 %p -XX:+PerfDisableSharedMem -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags -XX:+PrintGC -XX:+PrintGCApplicationConcurrentTime -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC -XX:+PrintPromotionFailure -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+ResizeTLAB -XX:StringTableSize=1000003 -XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42 -XX:ThreadStackSize=256 -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:-UseBiasedLocking -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap -XX:+UseCompressedClassPointers -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:+UseTLAB -XX:+UseThreadPriorities
```

After carefully removing a few flags it came down to "-XX:+AlwaysPreTouch".

Sigh.