# Java generic type issue

Tags: java, generics

Consider the following simplified example:

```
package com.test;

class B<S> {
    B(Class<S> clazz) {}
}

class A<T> {
    class SubB extends B<SubB> {
        SubB() {
            super(SubB.class);
        }
    }
}
```

Although IntelliJ is not showing any error (as it usually does when compile errors exist), the actual compilation when starting the program ends with error located in `super(SubB.class);`:

> Error:(8, 23) java: incompatible types: `java.lang.Class<com.test.A.SubB>` cannot be converted to `java.lang.Class<com.test.A<T>.SubB>`

I am curious, why is this happening? And how could I solve it?

Compilation is done with AdoptOpenJDK 11.

Comment: Eclipse reports a compiler error `The constructor B<A<T>.SubB>(Class<A.SubB>) is undefined`

Comment: Does it work if you remove `<T>`?

Comment: @assylias It does. Also works when `SubB` is made a top-level class. I suppose it would also work when `SubB` is made a static nested class.

Comment: Removing `<T>` is working but I really need that type parameter (in my real code).

Comment: Is it really necessary for `SubB` to be an inner class of A? Can you make it a nested class instead? (`static class SubB extends B<SubB>`)

Comment: @Eran yeah this should work but why is my example even a compilation error?

Comment: It seems to be because SubB is an inner class, so T is also part of SubB's type, but SubB.class cannot refer to T as there is only one SubB.class for every T.  Try making class SubB a `static class SubB`. Or try casting SubB.class to `Class<A<T>.SubB`.

Comment: Use some casts:`super((Class<A<T>.SubB>) (Class<?>) SubB.class);` The reason is somewhat complicated, will write it in an answer.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn the cast is working, even `super((Class<SubB>) (Class<?>) SubB.class);`... I'm super curious on your answer... thx all for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this behavior is a bit complicated. Consider `java.util.List.class`, which has the type `Class<java.util.List>`, not `Class<java.util.List<?>>`. This is a limitation of the class literal.

In your example, `SubB.class` has the type `Class<com.test.A.SubB>`, again with the raw type of SubB. But the constructor expects some type of `Class<com.test.A<T>.SubB>`.

That's why we need to cast the literal to it's desired type:

```
super((Class<SubB>) (Class<?>) SubB.class);
```

This will produce a warning, but a quick examination will show that there is nothing to worry about.

Comment: isn't that somehow related to type erasure?

Comment: 1) according to [this](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6184881), the fact that `getClass` will return a raw type is mandated by the specification, not sure if this is what you meant by limitation. 2) `....again with the raw type of SubB`, you mean `.. raw type of A`? 3) while the solution does work, IMHO it does explain _why_ that happens. Why would the constructor expect `Class<com.test.A<T>.SubB>`, why is that `A<T>` even part of the compiler messages considering that point (1) mandates the use of reified type, which would be `A.class`, not an impossible `A<T>.class`

Comment: and of course that once you cast to `Class<?>` - you can further cast to everything you want: `Class<Integer> c = (Class<Integer>) (Class<?>) SubB.class;`

Comment: @Eugene mind that `SubB` is not `static`, therefore, it has a type parameter (`T`), corresponding to its outer instance of `A<T>`. `SubB` can refer to `T` in its body, e.g. having methods accepting or returning `T`. Hence, `SubB` is a generic class and not reifiable, so `SubB.class` refers to the *raw type* `SubB` without an actual type argument for `T`. I do not agree with the answer’s conclusion that “a quick examination will show that there is nothing to worry about”. There is no problem with the question’s simplified example, but that’s surely not the real code.

Comment: A better solution is to use `class SubB extends B<A.SubB>` to emphasize that the type argument to `S` has a raw `A`. This eliminates the unchecked operation in the constructor and may raise warnings where it matters, at potential uses of `S` depending on `A` (if such places exist). (Or change `SubB` to `static`, if a dependency to an `A<T>` was not intended at all).

Comment: @Holger very interesting. is `SubB` really a generic class? I mean is `Inner` a generic class here for example? `static <E> void test(E e) {
        class Inner {

            void useE(E e) {

            }
        }
    }`

Comment: @Eugene Given a particular instance of `Inner`, you can't determine the actual parameter type of `useE` due to type erasure (and `getClass()` reflects the *raw type* of `Inner`). These are the typical attributes of generic classes. I don't know whether this name is specifically used for such a local type, but at least, it's a non-reifiable type, which is already enough to have all those problems.

Answer (score 2):

I found this very interesting.

The problem here is that when you declare this:

```
class A<T> {

    class SubB extends B<SubB> {
        SubB() {
            super...
        }
    }
}
```

that `B<SubB>` is *actually* `B<A<T>.SubB>` (I was not even aware this is possible). This is easy to prove thx for `javap` (just decompile the class and see for yourself). Once you write that in the "long" form:

```
class A<T> {
    class SubB extends B<A<T>.SubB> {
        SubB() {
            super(....);
        }
    }
}
```

it starts to make a lot more sense.

Ideally for this to work, you have to be able to write:

```
super(A<T>.SubB.class);
```

but java does not allow this, `.class` can only be invoked on raw types.

The best way to do it is to be explicit here:

```
class A<T> {
    class SubB extends B<A.SubB> {
        SubB() {
            super(SubB.class);
        }
    }
}
```

in saying: I am using the raw type of `A`: `B<A.SubB>`

Comment: That's interesting, indeed. Fun fact: IntelliJ shows a error on that `super(SubB.class)` but starting the program works.

Answer (score 1):

In generics the inheritance is not as we usually know, i.e
lets take an example 
class `ArrayList<String>` is not a subclass of `List`.
Whereas `List<String>` is not same as `List`.

Also in generics you will not generally get a compilation error easily since the Generic types are been transformed to their raw types during the compilation.

Hence we need to cast as mentioned by @JohannesKuhn.